# Making A Scoring System

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a scoring system for a candy crush game and I have just about done it. The problem I am having is with the last part and displaying the score on the actual page, Code is linked below, any and all help welcome. I tried using >document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score.toString();​ 
but no matter where I put it I got an error. Any help is appreciated.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/2rjhwkm6/

Samples:

This is where I add the score so that every time there are new chunks added the player gets points:

```
//make Candies falling down
function gravity() {
    for ( x = 0; x < tileNum; x++) {
        var hole = 0;
        for ( y = tileNum - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            if (!candyMatrix[x][y]) {
                hole++;
            } else {
                candyMatrix[x][y].reposition(x, y + hole);
            }
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < hole; i++) {
            var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            var candy = new Candy(color, x, i-hole);
            $("#game").append(candy.JQ);
            candy.JQ.css("display","none");
            candy.reposition(x,i);
            candy.JQ.fadeIn(fadeTime);
            score++;
```

EDIT: working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkygfu5d/
got the error SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8203'

Comment: Is http://jsfiddle.net/2rjhwkm6/ empty for others, too?

Comment: Your fiddle is empty

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: And, should you be calling `score.toString()`, not `score.toString` ?

Comment: See the edits. Not sure what happened. And yes I was using score.toString() (forgot the ())

Comment: That new fiddle still has errors. Looks like you're trying to link CandyCrush.js from your local machine? Please check your fiddles before posting. Also please explain how to trigger the error.

Comment: The I am not having issues with the fiddle and I removed the linking just incase. To get the error I attempted to put document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score.toString();​ in the js

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of CandyCrush.js, this seems to work for me:

```
document.getElementById('Score').innerHTML = score.toString();
```

[Working(ish) jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/gkygfu5d/2/).

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be working fine for me?

```
//make Candies falling down
function gravity() {
    for ( x = 0; x < tileNum; x++) {
        var hole = 0;
        for ( y = tileNum - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            if (!candyMatrix[x][y]) {
                hole++;
            } else {
                candyMatrix[x][y].reposition(x, y + hole);
            }
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < hole; i++) {
            var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            var candy = new Candy(color, x, i-hole);
            $("#game").append(candy.JQ);
            candy.JQ.css("display","none");
            candy.reposition(x,i);
            candy.JQ.fadeIn(fadeTime);
            score++;

        }
    }

    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score.toString();
    setTimeout(candyChain,moveTime);
}
```